# Syntax Check for JavaScript in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, aptana

Every time I deploy JavaScript I have to check the code in http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php .
I would like my IDE to do proper syntax check, but none of the JS Editors I have in Eclipse/Aptana is able to warn me for a simple omitting of a `;`, a `}` and the like. I use `Aptana Studio 3`, and I have installed the `Javascript Development Tools`, I changed the editor in window->preferences->file associations to everything possible but still, I dont get proper syntax highlighting. Does anybody know why?

P.S. Normal syntax highlighting, like strings in green and function names in brown works well.

Comment: event the jslint plugin I added does not do the job.

Comment: Nodeclipse comes with a Javascript editor that does some decent syntax analysis. You can install it from the Eclipse market place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Eclipse Web Tools with the JavaScript Developer Tools. I had to "**convert**" my (mostly Python) project **to a JavaScript project**. Now it seems to have both "natures", as I get syntax checking in both Python and JavaScript files.